# Why does Tycho include certain Eclipse plug-ins into a materialized product?

Tags: eclipse, tycho

I am using Tycho to build and package an Eclipse Workbench-based product. The product definition is based on features, not individual plug-ins. For some reason, the final build (the materialized product using `create-product-distributions` as described on the Tycho wiki pages) always contains many more plug-ins than I would have assumed. For instance, for some reason the JDT plug-ins (not the feature, though!) are pulled into the final product, even though none of the features created by me or imported as a dependency declare the JDT as a direct dependency. How can I debug the dependency resolution process, and how can I find out what is causing Tycho to pull in which plug-ins?

Comment: There is the _Plug-in Dependencies_ view and the _Features_ view for that. Maybe you do something wrong with optional dependencies. Show an example to reproduce this issue.